# Not able to Fill Dataset using Access OleDB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

Have been trying this for more than a few hours now. I am trying fill a dataset using Access Query. the query works fine in Access but does not fill anything in the Dataset. The query is a filter of a view. 
Example:-

```
Select Column1  as MyList 
from (Select * from mytable 
where Column1 like "'*" & Textbox1.Text &"*'"
or Column2 like "'*" & Textbox1.Text &"*'" 
or Column3 like "'*" & Textbox1.Text &"*'")
union all
Select Column2 
from (Select * from mytable 
where Column1 like "'*" & Textbox1.Text &"*'"
or Column2 like "'*" & Textbox1.Text &"*'"
or Column3 like "'*" & Textbox1.Text &"*'")
union all 
Select Column3
from (Select * from mytable 
where Column1 like "'*" & Textbox1.Text &"*'" 
or Column2 like "'*" & Textbox1.Text &"*'" 
or Column3 like "'*" & Textbox1.Text &"*'")
```

I use the set the query as a string and use DataAdapter to fill in the Dataset. 
But this doesn't work. I don't get any error. The data just doesn't show up in the Dataset.

Code:-

```
Dim da as new OledbAdapter(sqlstring,myconn)
Dim ds as New Dataset

myconn.open()
da.fill(ds,"TableName")
myconn.close()
```

I believe this has something to do with access query when the lookup table is a view. Any suggestions/workarounds would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Aamir

Comment: Why do you have a double single quote at the end of each line? Replace it with &"*'" & _

Comment: just came back late and typed it in. sorry mate. Have fixed that

Comment: _Dim cmd = "SELECT ....... WHERE Column1 Like '*" & textBox1.Text & "*' or Column2 Like '*" & textBox2.Text & "*'   ......... "_

Comment: However all this mess of string concatenation should be totally removed and a parameterized query used to replace the actual text

Comment: With OleDb, you must use ANSI wildcards in your `Like` comparisons, so substitute `%` for `*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of concatenating strings you should use a parameterized query. Concatenations often produces incorrect syntax. Sometime this is caused by a missing quote or other simple typing error, sometimes the cause is the presence of a single quote inside the value concatenated to the query text. Finally, albeit more difficult to exploit in MS-Access, string concatenation leads to [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) attacks.

Try to use a parameterized query like this

```
Dim cmd = "Select Column1  as MyList from (Select * from mytable " & _
    "where Column1 like @p1 or Column2 like @p2 or Column3 like @p3) " & _
"union all " & _
    "Select Column2 from (Select * from mytable " & _
    "where Column1 like @p4 or Column2 like @p5 or Column3 like @p6) " & _
"union all " & _
    "Select Column3 from (Select * from mytable " & _
    "where Column1 like @p7 or Column2 like @p8 or Column3 like @p9)"

Dim da as new OledbAdapter(cmd,myconn)
Dim text1 = "%" & textBox1.Text & "%"
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = text1
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = text1
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@p3", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = text1
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@p4", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = text1
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@p5", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = text1
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@p6", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = text1
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@p7", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = text1
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@p8", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = text1
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@p9", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = text1
Dim ds as New Dataset

myconn.open()
da.fill(ds,"TableName")
```

Notice that I have been forced to add 9 parameters to the SelectCommand parameters collection also if you have really just one value. This is caused by the OleDb provider that doesn't support named parameters and requires a value for every parameter placeholder (the @pX) present in the query text. In any case this approach is a lot safer, cleaner and easier to maintain

Comment: Thanks Steve. That worked. The only difference I noticed was % used in the textbox string variable as compared to * in my string query. Surprised it still worked with % for wildcard search